# hex to base 62 conversion for URL shortening

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm looking to convert 24-character long hex mongoDB object IDs to base62 format so that it's shorter for URLs. I don't want to convert from hex to integer and then to base62. Is there code that already does this?

Comment: sure... what last two characters do you suggest?

Comment: Can you use a `-` and an underscore?

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://elenzil.com/esoterica/baseConversion.html) can convert between arbitrary bases/alphabets.

Consider using Base58 if you're using it for URLs, as it will be easier for people to type in without confusing similar-looking characters.

Comment: Converting `47cc67093475061e3d95369d` from `0123456789abcdef` to `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_` doesn't work properly using this algorithm. I noticed that there's an intermediate step where he converts it to integer, which I think Javascript stores at a floating point.

Comment: I don't know how the conversion would be possible without determining the characters' integer values, but also I don't see why the integer would be stored as a floating point. I'm sorry that I wasn't much help after all.

Answer (score 1):

Because 64 is a multiple of 16, the best way to do this is with a look up table.  Any triple of hex digits is represented by two base64 digits, so you will need 16³ = 64² = 4096 entries in each look up table to make this happen.

I have a perl script that will generate the mappings at https://gist.github.com/3730664

I also have a full implementation of the generation and conversion functions (again in perl) that I am using to convert MongoDB ids if that would be useful let me know.

Edit:  I have added the full implementation I am using to the gist linked above.

Answer (score 1):

node [int-encoder](https://github.com/alanclarke/int-encoder) does this

```
npm install int-encoder

var en = require('int-encoder');

//simple integer conversion
en.encode(12345678); // "ZXP0"
en.decode('ZXP0'); // 12345678

//convert big hex number using optional base argument
en.encode('e6c6b53d3c8160b22dad35a0f705ec09', 16); // 'hbDcW9aE89tzLYjDgyzajJ'
en.decode('hbDcW9aE89tzLYjDgyzajJ', 16); // 'e6c6b53d3c8160b22dad35a0f705ec09'
```

Answer (score 1):

### LZ-string

You could use lz-string to compress your strings.

I'd suggest you use their function `compressToBase64` to compress and `decompressFromBase64` to decompress.

You could use their regular compress & decompress function but your compressed string will probably have all kinds of weird chinese characters in it.

You can find a guide on how to download and use lz-string [here](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code, written in C#, convert the logic into whatever language you want. you can also change the order or characters in the namespace to make the conversion unique for you.

```
public static class ShortCodes
{
    private static Random rand = new Random();

    // You may change the "shortcode_Keyspace" variable to contain as many or as few characters as you
    // please.  The more characters that aer included in the "shortcode_Keyspace" constant, the shorter
    // the codes you can produce for a given long.
const string shortcode_Keyspace = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    // Arbitrary constant for the maximum length of ShortCodes generated by the application.
const int shortcode_maxLen = 12;


    public static string LongToShortCode(long number)
    {
        int ks_len = shortcode_Keyspace.Length;
        string sc_result = "";
        long num_to_encode = number;
        long i = 0;
        do
        {
            i++;
            sc_result = shortcode_Keyspace[(int)(num_to_encode % ks_len)] + sc_result;
            num_to_encode = ((num_to_encode - (num_to_encode % ks_len)) / ks_len);
        }
        while (num_to_encode != 0);
        return sc_result;
    }


    public static long ShortCodeToLong(string shortcode)
    {
        int ks_len = shortcode_Keyspace.Length;
        long sc_result = 0;
        int sc_length = shortcode.Length;
        string code_to_decode = shortcode;
        for (int i = 0; i < code_to_decode.Length; i++)
        {
            sc_length--;
            char code_char = code_to_decode[i];
            sc_result += shortcode_Keyspace.IndexOf(code_char) * (long)(Math.Pow((double)ks_len, (double)sc_length));
        }
        return sc_result;
    }
}
```